# ArcMap: error when selecting attribute records

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

At 10.8.1 I need to select all records from a shapefile string attribute field where the left-most character is blank (that is, a single whitespace).  For guidance, I rely on the onboard ESRI Help documentation by searching for "`SQL reference for query expressions`" (screenshot below). Following that Help example, I use the following expression:

```
LEFT (field_name, 1) = ' '
```

Unfortunately the selection fails with the error

> An invalid SQL statement was used.

When I surround the field name with double-quotes (not two single quotes), as in:

```
LEFT ("field_name", 1) = ' '
```

The same error occurs.

This should be so simple!  Is the [Esri documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm) wrong? What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I'd have used "`substring(field_name,1,1) = ' '`".  The only documentation reference I found showed a VBScript language function "Left", so the location of your screenshot should be included in the question.  Note that each data source has a different implementation of "SQL", many not that complete (shapefile in particular).

Comment: Vince, your suggestion works - thanks!  If you want to reformat it as an answer I'd be happy to give it my vote.  I'm also updating my OP to show how I accessed the ESRI LEFT() help.

Comment: It's incomplete in your quote (which is not a link; the [online documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm) is kept up to date), but the line after you referenced the LEFT function is `Refer to the documentation of your DBMS for a list of supported functions.` To me, this indicates that it only applies to SQL RDBMS solutions.  Shapefiles do *not* have a backing SQL engine. It is unfortunate that the doc references `LEFT`, since `LEFT` is not in the list of supported functions below. I've reported it.

Comment: Good catch about that following line, and thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Also, I wasn't aware that the onboard (is that the correct term?) documentation wasn't kept up-to-date.  A pity...

Comment: While patches may update the embedded doc, the "latest" web doc tree is maintained realtime.